How to get the difference between two rows gruping by columns in Azure Monitor KQL
I want to get difference value between two rows in Azure Log Analytics Workspace in KQL.
I can get them each host separately using "| where Hostname == 'host01'", "| extend Difference = Coalesce(Value - prev(Value), double(0))", but I want to get all hosts of them at once.
Sample data:



TimeGenerated
Hostname
Value




2024-01-01T00:10:00
host01
12


2024-01-01T00:10:00
host02
24


2024-01-01T00:10:00
host03
35


2024-01-01T00:00:00
host01
10


2024-01-01T00:00:00
host02
20


2024-01-01T00:00:00
host03
30



Expected result Output:



TimeGenerated
Hostname
Difference




2024-01-01T00:10:00
host01
2


2024-01-01T00:10:00
host02
4


2024-01-01T00:10:00
host03
5



Thanks in advance.

Below KQL Query worked for me:
let RithTable = datatable(TimeGenerated: datetime, Hostname: string, Value: int)
[
    datetime(2024-01-01T00:10:00), "host01", 12,
    datetime(2024-01-01T00:10:00), "host02", 24,
    datetime(2024-01-01T00:10:00), "host03", 35,
    datetime(2024-01-01T00:00:00), "host01", 10,
    datetime(2024-01-01T00:00:00), "host02", 20,
    datetime(2024-01-01T00:00:00), "host03", 30
];
let test1=RithTable
| summarize Test= make_set(Value) by Hostname
| extend Test=array_sort_desc(Test)
| extend y=toint(Test[0]),z=toint(Test[1])
| extend diff= y-z
| project-away Test,y,z;
RithTable
| summarize Time=max(TimeGenerated) by Hostname
| join kind=inner test1 on Hostname
| project-reorder Time,Hostname,diff
| project-away Hostname1

Output:

Fiddle.
